# MATLAB : class structure

Tags: matlab, class

A code was given to me and it's a class with several methods, etc and the code is about 10,000 lines long. My question seem dumb but I didn't find a suitable response elsewhere : is there a way to get the stucture of the code ? Like a panel on the left with

```
Methods
   > function fun1
   > function fun2
   > function fun3
   > function fun4
```

Indeed there is the solution of colapsing everything, but it's not convinient for my puposes. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing

```
doc <classname>
```

at the MATLAB command prompt will open the help browser with a list of properties and methods defined for the class.

You can also type

```
methods <classname>
```

To get a list of defined methods written to the command window.